# Why use OR TRUE operator in script with set -e?

Tags: shell

I'm looking at a [simple shell script](https://github.com/afiskon/install-couchdb) that I found on github to install CouchDB 2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.  It has these lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
...
sudo apt-get update || true
...
```

What is the `|| pipe` component doing? I.e. what is being piped to `true` and why? As far as I can tell, when I run it on my server I get the same result as running the `apt-get update` command without piping.

Previously, if I wanted to update/install packages I would do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Does piping to `true` result in the upgrade command being run? Also, can I assume that everything in a shell/bash script happens synchronously?

Comment: It's not a pipe, it's logical or: if the first command doesn't have exit status 0 (success), execute the second command. This makes sure that the exit status of this line is always 0. Is the `-e` shell option set? This kind of thing is often seen when it is. (Edit: just checked, `set -e` *is* set.)

Comment: changed the title, since I was horribly off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` is not a pipe operator. It is a shell operator meaning "or". It only executes the following command if the preceding command fails. Since `true` always succeeds, and otherwise does nothing, the only point of `|| true` is to ensure that the compound command succeeds.

Normally this is unnecessary, but you can put the shell into terminate-on-failure mode with [`set -e`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin). In that case, any script command which fails will cause the script to immediately terminate. (This is sometimes done in order to avoid  having to check the status of every command, but it is not generally recommended as best practice.)

With `set -e`, it is sometimes desirable to ignore failure for certain commands (such as `apt-get update`); appending `||true` to such a command will guarantee success and allow the script to continue even if the update fails.

Comment: Thanks. I should have seen that as an `OR`, and not a pipe